# Spring Batch Java Config JobLauncherTestUtils

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-java-config

I am currently working on a spring boot project that uses spring batch. I am trying to use JavaConfig instead of xml but it's difficult with all of the docs currently in xml.

I followed https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/06/spring-batch-2-2-javaconfig-part-5-modular-configurations but am having difficulties using the `JobLauncherTestUtils`. I know I need to tell the test to use the correct spring context, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My test looks like the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class, MyJobConfiguration.class})
public class RetrieveDividendsTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a TestExecutionListener annotation to the test class to inject the configured application context?

`@TestExecutionListeners( {DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
     })`

Have a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html#testingIndividualSteps to see how a job and how a single step is tested there.

Comment: @Sander_M but to do that I need to have `JobLauncherTestUtils` working which is my issue. I'm trying to do an end-to-end or individual step test, not just testing the components.

Answer (score 10):

I stumbled upon the same issue and had a look at [this XML configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/test/resources/job-runner-context.xml) from the Spring Batch samples. Based on that I managed to get it working with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { BatchTest.BatchTestConfig.class })
public class BatchTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void demo() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();

        Assert.assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getStatus());
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    static class BatchTestConfig {

        @Bean
        JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
            return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        }

        // rest omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

The test succeeds and my `ItemWriter` logs the processed elements as expected.

Comment: For some reason with this approach I got "No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' available" until I moved/upped BatchTestConfig to its own class. A quirk of Spring I've somehow never encountered or a bug I don't know... Otherwise +1

Comment: I have the same error, even after moving the BatchTestConfig to its own class. Getting `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: @NicolasWidart the part `// rest omitted for brevity` contains a definition of a Job bean: `@Bean public Job myJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) { ... }`. It sounds to me you're not configuring your Spring Batch pipeline properly.

Comment: Oh I see, but then I'll have a duplicate of the job configuration which is already done in its config file no ?

Comment: @NicolasWidart Can you load your non-test config in your test context and use the configured beans from there? Be mindful of duplicate beans of specific types (i.e. those you do need to have twice because you may need to change certain config steps for your test environment).

Answer (score 1):

For spring Batch 4.1.x or above  Version We can use `@SpringBatchTest` annotation that will automatically inject `jobLauncherTestUtils`  , check sample example for more details [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/testing.html#endToEndTesting)

This is how you can created if u cant upgrade to 4.1.x or above

```
@Bean
     public JobLauncherTestUtils getJobLauncherTestUtils(){

            return new JobLauncherTestUtils() {
                @Override
                @Autowired
                public void setJob(@Qualifier("myjobname") Job job) {
                    super.setJob(job);
                }
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following in your pom.xml?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If I'm not mistaken, and you use spring boot, it should load the auto-configuration beans of spring batch for you so they will be available for injection.

Comment: Yes I have the dependency. The code compiles just can't get the context correct.

Comment: Spring boot use the following pattern to find your configuration in test environment: 1) search for the closest `@SpringBootApplication` in your test package. 2) search for the closest `@SpringBootApplication` in your main package. Do you have any of those? if not you can create one in your test pakcage with a `@ComponentScan` that search for your `@Configuration` files.